# Как интегрировать SaaS contract/subscription product on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon

Я пытаюсь [интеграция](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/saas-integrate-contract.html) разобраться как выполнить первый этап интеграции Saas продукта на AWS Marketplase.
Подскажите пожалуйста, кто писал подобный код, как используя [AWS SDK for Java V2] выполнить хотя бы первый этап интеграции. Среди документации AWS такого не нашел.

Согласно документации:
Exchange the token for a **CustomerIdentifier**, **CustomerAWSAccountId**, and **ProductCode** by calling the **ResolveCustomer API operation** in the AWS Marketplace Metering Service.
Как из токена получить вышеуказанные значения, используя AWS SDK for Java V2?
Или что-то другое, поддерживающее лямбда вычисления на AWS.